# Publishing to Arxiv with Hyperlinks

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, urls, arxiv

In addressing this question the first thing to note is that everything works, compiles and displays correctly on my computer. However, when I go to upload my document to arXiv.org sometimes things change. In particular, publishing URLs in a bibliography to the arXiv.org is (apparently) very difficult.

Issue 1: Bibliography not showing up at all.

Issue 1 Solved: [Publishing to Arxiv using Biblatex-Biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181169/publishing-to-arxiv-using-biblatex-biber)

Issue 2: Bibliography displays urls outside the border of the document. It doesn't wrap the text of the url in a bibliography item. Again, it works fine on my computer, just not on the website arXiv.org.

Issue 2 Solved: [Line breaks of long URLs in biblatex bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134191/line-breaks-of-long-urls-in-bibliography)

Issue 3: With the setup from the first two issues, I now have a new problem. If a URL wraps to a new line, like this

```
[5] Author. Title. PhD thesis. Place, May 2011. url: http://aaaaaaaaaaa.a
    aaaaaaa/aaaaaaa.aaaaaaaa/aaaaaaa.aaa.aaaaaa.
```

arXiv.org disables the hyperlink. Again, hyperlinks are not disabled and work perfectly fine on my system. But wrapped urls on arXiv.org no longer have hyperlinks. If a bibliography item looks like

```
[6] Author. Title. PhD thesis. Place, May 2011. DOI: aaaa.aaa/a.aaa.aa
```

so that it does not break, the the hyperlink stays intact.

How do I solve issue 3? I am surprised that this is not a more common issue, considering the extensive use of the arXiv.

MWE:

test.TEX

```
%Document Type
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
%Bibliography Commands
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,firstinits=true,backend=bibtex,%backref=true,
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,incollection,phdthesis,misc]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{publisher}{\textnormal{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,phdthesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}
%Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,caption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,trees}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hyperindex,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue, citecolor=red, colorlinks=true}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
Reference \cite{one} and \cite{two}. 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

test.BIB

```
@ARTICLE{one,
url = {http://www.google.com}}
@Article{two,
url = {https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182523/publishing-to-arxiv-with-hyperlinks?noredirect=1#comment420451_182523}}
```

If you compile this on a local system it works fine. But if you try to publish this to the arXiv, it no longer has a hyperlink for the second item.

Comment: Hard to do much for you without a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) but have you tried [including a file `00README.XXX` with the line `nohypertex`](http://arxiv.org/help/00README#nohypertex)? Most issues where something appears different when processed on arXiv vs locally can be fixed this way.

Comment: @LevBishop Just tried your suggestion and it didn't work either. Not sure how a minimal working example will help, since it works fine on my system and fails to work arXiv. You could just try to upload any old document. Anyway, I will add a MWE for completeness sake.

Comment: _considering the extensive use of the arXiv_: remember this depends on you 'point of view'. ArXiv is big for physics but not for (say) chemistry, where sending a paper to a preprint server would prevent publication in a journal.

Comment: @JosephWright My comment had nothing to do with particular fields, where clearly different fields have different preferences. In terms of numbers of publications that arXiv receives per day, I think my comment is well justified (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArXiv). I only made this comment because I found it surprising that this issue had not been addressed before. About 99.99% of the time, my simple questions are answered with a quick Google search; but not this time. :-(

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With the MWE I can see that arXiv was processing your submission with `latex` instead of `pdflatex`. You can force `pdflatex` by including a line

```
\pdfoutput=1
```

within the first 5 lines of your submission, in which case everything seems to work. See [the arXiv help on this point](http://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex#pdflatex).

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! Worked great. I don't know how I would have every figured that out.

Comment: Best answer to this question for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the answers (also in the linked questions) worked in my case, here is the particular setup that ended up working for me *on arxiv*. The `hyperref` package is already preloaded by arxiv, so loading it again resulted in a compilation error.

```
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}
%\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}

\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX! Can you please make your code snippet -- as usual here -- compilable for a fast proof?

Answer (score 0):

arXiv's default behavior is to set the hyperref value for `breaklinks` to be `false`. This may change in the future, but you can account for this in your `\hypersetup` by just setting this keyvalue.