# Arxiv Latex Upload Error

Tags: pdftex, pdfpages, arxiv

I tried uploading my PDF files (generated from Latex) to Arxiv, but things did not work (arxiv wants its authors to upload the source). While, looking for answers on StackOverFlow, I found this [Solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186068/how-to-upload-latex-generated-pdf-paper-to-arxiv-without-latexxsources)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfinfo={
    Title={Blah Blah Blah},
    Author={Blah Blah Blah },
    Subject={If you want to put something here, do so},
    Keywords={Add some keywords if you feel so inclined}
  }
}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-last]{icailcameraready.pdf}
\end{document}
```

But, When I try to upload both the .tex file (as shown above) and the PDF, I get the below shown log file from arxiv.

```
    TeX log 

[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: <icailcameraready.pdf>   is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <arXiv_Paper.tex>    is of type 'LATEX2e'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'arXiv_Paper.tex'
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hlatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1297906/ && latex 'arXiv_Paper.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./arXiv_Paper.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2011-07-01, ngerman-x-2011-07-01, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian,
icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, marathi, or
iya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kurmanji,
lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk, pol
ish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, slovak, sloven
ian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded
.
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (default): hdvips.

(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def)))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pppdftex.def
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/ppnull.def

Package pdfpages Warning: I will use a dummy \includepdf command
(pdfpages) which will NOT insert any pages, because
(pdfpages) you are producing DVI output.

)))

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
... 

l.14 \begin
{document}
? 
! Emergency stop.
... 

l.14 \begin
{document}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on arXiv_Paper.log.

[verbose]: latex 'arXiv_Paper.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running latex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1297906/ && latex 'arXiv_Paper.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./arXiv_Paper.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2011-07-01, ngerman-x-2011-07-01, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian,
icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, marathi, or
iya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kurmanji,
lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk, pol
ish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, slovak, sloven
ian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded
.
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (default): hdvips.

(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def)))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pppdftex.def
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/ppnull.def

Package pdfpages Warning: I will use a dummy \includepdf command
(pdfpages) which will NOT insert any pages, because
(pdfpages) you are producing DVI output.

)))
No file arXiv_Paper.aux.
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.


Package pdfpages Warning: I cannot determine the number of pages of the
(pdfpages) included document, while being in DVI mode. You
(pdfpages) can use the option `lastpage' to give me a hint.

[1] (./arXiv_Paper.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `arXiv_Paper.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck) Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck) or use package `bookmark'.

)
Output written on arXiv_Paper.dvi (1 page, 2388 bytes).
Transcript written on arXiv_Paper.log
```

While, it says Sucess, the pdf generated is just a single page (Also thats what it say when I read the log file).

Comment: The log says it all: you're using `latex` as opposed to `pdflatex` and `\includepdf` can't work.

Comment: The instructions http://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex can be somewhat confusing. If all components of what you are intending to submit are not labeled clearly and included the system tends to reject it. A complete, self-contained, PDFlatex file worked form me, but I did not include pictures or bibtex separately.

Comment: @egreg and **Leucippus**. Thanks for the reply, it works now. I added  `\pdfoutput=1` to the existing .tex file. ArXiv accepts the submission now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As suggested, I added the below shown line to the .tex file and it works :).

```
  \pdfoutput=1
```

Answer (score 17):

The log file you get says it all:

```
Package pdfpages Warning: I will use a dummy \includepdf command
(pdfpages) which will NOT insert any pages, because
(pdfpages) you are producing DVI output.
```

You need that your submission is processed with `pdflatex`, not with the `latex` engine that arXiv uses by default.

From the help page of arXiv, http://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex

> **Considerations for PDFLaTeX submissions**
>
> arXiv fully supports and recognizes PDFLaTeX. You can ensure pdflatex processing by setting `\pdfoutput=1` within the first 5 lines of the preamble of the main pdflatex file. You should not need any other special flag. However since this is a relatively new feature, we urge you to carefully verify the PDF arXiv generates and to report any problems which may surface.
>
> - Should you need conditional branching in your source, use the `ifpdf` package. Do not re-invent the wheel. `ifpdf` provides a robust and well tested mechanism to distinguish between pdflatex in pdf mode and other modes or engines.
> - Some packages may require a particular back-end driver, in the form of a package option, e.g. `\usepackage[pdftex]{...}`. However, the `graphics` and `hyperref` packages determine the proper driver automatically; you don't have to make this explicit choice and should not do so to avoid conflicts.
> - You can use the full range of pdf specific hypertex options to augment metadata in the PDF file, e.g. `\hypersetup{pdfauthor={some author},pdftitle={eye-catching title}}`.
> - Figures can be included in JPEG, PNG, or PDF format with the standard graphics package. For security reasons arXiv does not allow for automated format conversion, so your figures must be in the proper format already.
> - Unlike native LaTeX, the default output format for PDFLaTeX is PDF, with no intermediate DVI or PostScript. Thus, these formats are not available for download for PDFLaTeX submissions.

So the best solution to your problem is starting the main file with

```
\pdfoutput=1

\documentclass[...]{...}
```