# not able to upload latex pdf on arxiv

Tags: arxiv, online

I have tried many ways to upload a paper on arxiv, but every time it failed.
I have uploaded latex source also, and pdf also. Every time it is failing.  I have also removed errors in the overleaf. Please help me to resolve this issue, I am trying from 2 days.

Comment: This is one for arXiv support

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the main issue raised in the query would appear to be unrelated to TeX, LaTeX, and friends.

Comment: On which platform, I have to ask this question?please tell

Comment: Have you seen this tread? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254198/arxiv-latex-upload-error