Included pdf figure is not displayed
I am trying to include a pdf figure into my main.tex but do not see anything. The figure pdf file is generated by me through the command
pdflatex -shell-escape "C:\Users\saro.harutyunyan\Downloads\IsoTetr-v2\figures\inverted.tex"

on my computer.
This is the code of the figure file inverted.tex:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}


\begin{document}

\definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49019607843137253,0.49019607843137253,1}
\definecolor{sexdts}{rgb}{0.1803921568627451,0.49019607843137253,0.19607843137254902}
\definecolor{qqzzcc}{rgb}{0,0.6,0.8}
\definecolor{ffvvqq}{rgb}{1,0.3333333333333333,0}
\definecolor{yqqqyq}{rgb}{0.5019607843137255,0,0.5019607843137255}
\definecolor{qqffqq}{rgb}{0,1,0}
\definecolor{dtsfsf}{rgb}{0.8274509803921568,0.1843137254901961,0.1843137254901961}
\definecolor{ffqqff}{rgb}{1,0,1}
\definecolor{ffccww}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.4}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,x=1cm,y=1cm]

\clip(-8,-3) rectangle (10,8.5);

\coordinate (A_1) at (1.12,0.64);
\coordinate (B_1) at (-0.77,2.47);
\coordinate (C_1) at (-2.67,2.19);
\coordinate (D) at (-0.67,4.32);
\coordinate (N) at (-2.67,1.15);

% \draw [fill=qqzzcc, opacity=0.1, draw=none] (0.31,2.43) circle (2.1745024706960563cm);
\draw [fill=sexdts, opacity=0.05, draw=none] (3.39,3.74) circle (4.403331765230275cm);
\draw [fill=dtsfsf, opacity=0.05, draw=none] (-2.67, 1.15) circle (3.834417221157338cm);
\tkzDefPoint(0.31,2.43){P}
\tkzDefPoint(0.31+2.1745024706960563,2.43){P'}
\tkzDrawCircle[fill=qqzzcc, fill opacity=0.1, draw=none](P, P')

\draw [line width=2pt,color=qqffqq] (C_1)-- (D);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=qqffqq] (D)-- (B_1);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=qqffqq] (D)-- (A_1);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=qqffqq] (A_1)-- (C_1);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=qqffqq] (C_1)-- (B_1);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=qqffqq] (B_1)-- (A_1);

\draw [line width=1.2pt,dashed,color=ffccww] (N)-- (3.39,3.74);

\draw [rotate around={170.3348329857469:(-0.7690817835777952,1.4191366106964343)},line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt,color=yqqqyq] (-0.7690817835777952,1.4191366106964343) ellipse (2.21266714986076cm and 1.0382141112579526cm);
\draw [rotate around={170.51219819069087:(0.16516231757413458,1.553585723622613)},line width=1.2pt,color=ffvvqq] (0.16516231757413458,1.553585723622613) ellipse (1.9264782511768004cm and 0.9028741752809536cm);
\draw [rotate around={-9.580821647096087:(3.0933489290969085,1.966351307654744)},line width=1.2pt,color=ffvvqq] (3.0933489290969085,1.966351307654744) ellipse (3.901668862973618cm and 1.8303600712545698cm);
\draw [rotate around={-67.10445936319061:(0.07212956304164497,2.313048243936575)},line width=1.2pt,color=ffccww] (0.07212956304164497,2.313048243936575) ellipse (2.1565112229553636cm and 0.734447808090833cm);

\draw [line width=1.2pt,dashed,color=xdxdff] (N)-- (-0.026701,3.568);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dashed,color=xdxdff] (N)-- (4.3260653467112,-0.11918622137805479);

\begin{scriptsize}

\draw [fill=black] (A_1) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.28,0.4) node {$A_1$};
\draw [fill=black] (B_1) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=black] (-0.47,2.7) node {$B_1$};
\draw [fill=black] (C_1) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=black] (-3,2.33) node {$C_1$};
\draw [fill=black] (D) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=black] (-0.6263516518685175,4.64) node {$D$};

\draw [fill=ffccww] (0.31,2.43) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=ffccww] (3.39,3.74) circle (1.5pt);

\draw [fill=ffqqff] (-0.71,2.15) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=ffqqff] (-1.02,2.2) node {$X_1$};
\draw [fill=ffqqff] (-1.71,1.96) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=ffqqff] (-1.95,2.1) node {$Y_1$};
\draw [fill=dtsfsf] (N) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=dtsfsf] (-2.97,1.1) node {$N$};
\draw [fill=black] (-1.47,-0.35) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=black] (-1.1,-0.3) node {$O_1$};

\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

This is the code of main.tex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[bb=-8 -8 8 8]{inverted.pdf}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:inverted}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

main.tex is run in overleaf. Strangely there are no any compilation errors:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=latex 2023.8.28)  13 MAY 2024 11:42
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-06-30>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 107.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def
File: dvips.def 2022/09/22 v3.1e Graphics/color driver for dvips
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen141
\Gin@req@width=\dimen142
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def
File: l3backend-dvips.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: dvips
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count193
\l__pdf_backend_content_box=\box52
\l__pdf_backend_model_box=\box53
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count194
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count195
\g__pdf_backend_link_sf_int=\count196
) (./output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
File: inverted.pdf Graphic file (type eps)
<inverted.pdf> [1

] (./output.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-06-30>
 ***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 861 strings out of 475238
 15107 string characters out of 5764596
 1917241 words of memory out of 5000000
 22165 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558069 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 57i,5n,65p,181b,198s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

Output written on output.dvi (1 page, 396 bytes).

What could the problem possibly be? Thanks in advance!

You are creating a dvi and not a pdf, is that intended?

No I need pdf. When I run the command mentioned in my question I get an inverted.pdf file which is indeed pdf. Or you are asking about main.tex? If so, I need it to be in pdf too, not dvi.

Well your main is currently a dvi, so switch the engine to pdflatex instead of latex.

The problem is that these are the files of my article which I should upload to arxiv.org. Their compiler is
pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=latex)
This is why I am using latex and not pdflatex.

latex with backend dvips cannot include PDFs. You should convert them to EPS first (or use pdflatex, lualatex or xelatex, because these three can include PDFs).

You can force arxiv to use pdflatex.

Yes, I see cabohah, thanks.
Yes @UlrikeFischer, I saw the solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254198/arxiv-latex-upload-error. Thanks.
