# TeXLive 2016 for Windows

Tags: texlive, installing, texlive-2016

Do anyone have the TexLive 2016 installer for Windows? I can't find it on their website.

Comment: why would you want 2016? (you can get an archived version but it is frozen code with no live  updates) texlive 2017 has been out for some months.

Comment: TeXLive 2017 didn't have some math packages, the last time I installed, about two months ago.

Comment: @SubhajitMishra Which packages?

Comment: I think it was some commutative diagram package in tikz. I exactly don't remember the package name.

Comment: @SubhajitMishra it is _very_ rare for packages to be withdrawn, unless they are found not to have a valid licence, in which case they can't be used from texlive 2016 either. In any case it makes no sense to backdate _all_ the binaries to unsupported versions just to avoid getting one `.sty` file from ctan  if it is not in the default texlive 2017  install.

Comment: @SubhajitMishra If the package is still on CTAN, you can download it and install it manually.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Archived versions of texlive between 1996 and 2017 are available from

ftp://tug.org/texlive/historic/

However there are really very few reasons why you would want to install an obsolete version. It is an archived state with no live updates or bug fixes.

Comment: Unfortunately the preprint server https://arxiv.org/ uses and *requires* the 2016 version; see https://arxiv.org/help/faq/texlive

It isn't even possible to prepare a PDF with the most recent Texlive and just upload that instead. Otherwise they'll complain that the pdf is tex-generated, and demand that you upload the tex source instead - which must be compilable by their Texlive 2016. Really nonsensical policy...

Comment: @pglpm that is sort of true but millions of people upload documents to arxiv that they have prepared locally without going to the extremes of installing an old texlive locally. The few cases where there are package differences between texlive 2016 and texlive 2020 are more or less well known and solutions can be found if you search arxiv on this site.

Comment: Thank you David, I'll actually look here then. Last time I remember I had problems with bibliography style files, and even including the appropriate sty and config files didn't seem to help. In the end I gave up and downgraded to 2016. But I wasn't on StackExchange then :) I see there are also posts about how to "fool" arXiv's checker: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/186068/97039