# How to upload LaTeX-generated pdf paper to arXiv (2019)

Tags: arxiv

Submitting to arXiv remains unnecessarily cumbersome and some of the answers in the [previous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186068/how-to-upload-latex-generated-pdf-paper-to-arxiv-without-latex-sources) thread are outdated or lead to bad results.

I wanted to ask, what are up to date solutions to submit a pdf to arXiv? The microsoft pdf printer seems to work, but the results are less then optimal. Text becomes unselectable and references can't be followed.

I am aware that I should submit the original latex sources, but the rather harsh restrictions on Latex source make this a complex endeavor, especially for submissions in the field of graphics. Right now, I'd have to convert images to jpg and resize them, thereby losing the original high resolution data. This is not okay and I won't do that. I could do it specifically for arXiv, but this would mean I had to repeat the same procedure whenever I'd need to update the arXiv submission. That's also not a sustainable solution.

Edit: Also, I tried a latex submission now but I'm getting compiler errors. I chose to use overleaf specifically because I do not want to deal with latex compiler errors from various build systems so this is not something that encourages to submit latex sources to arxiv either.

Comment: Welcome! AFAIK you *can* submit pdf files to the arXiv. However, I doubt that you can circumvent the upload restrictions that way. That is, if the included pdf files are huge, so will be the file you wish to upload. Notice that sometimes arXiv people are willing to make an exception.

Comment: You can't submit pdf files that were generated from latex. arXiv does some checks to evaluate whether the pdf originated from latex.

Comment: Noone here can recommend anything unless you give information about the errors. Arxiv has their reasons as to why they do it the way they do. Using overleaf does not magically make your document less complicated for systems to deal with.

Comment: Welcome. It would be better to ask a question about your actual problem, which here seems to be avoiding "convert images to jpg and resize them, thereby losing the original high resolution data".