# Compiling errors on arXiv

Tags: compiling, arxiv

I am having difficulty uploading a document to arXiv because of compiling errors. I am using biblatex 3.5 with biber 2.6. It compiles fine on my computer. Here is a MWE which fails on arXiv. I compile with PDFLatex, biber, PDFLatex, etc. I then upload the .bbl file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,url=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{MyLibrary3}

\begin{document}

Words \cite{BoydParikhChuPeleatoEckstein2011_distributed}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This has .bib file:

```
@article{BoydParikhChuPeleatoEckstein2011_distributed,
  title = {Distributed Optimization and Statistical Learning via the Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers},
  volume = {3},
  url = {http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2185816},
  number = {1},
  journaltitle = {Foundations and Trends\textregistered in Machine Learning},
  author = {Boyd, Stephen and Parikh, Neal and Chu, Eric and Peleato, Borja and Eckstein, Jonathan},
  date = {2011},
  pages = {1--122}
}
```

I get the following error when I try to upload to arXiv.

```
 Package biblatex Warning: File 'arXivSubmission.bbl' created by wrong version.

(./arXivSubmission.bbl
! Undefined control sequence.
l.21 \sortlist
[entry]{nty/global/}
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.21 \sortlist
[entry]{nty/global/}
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on arXivSubmission.log.
```

I'm using the latest version of biblatex and biber, and it's not clear what version arXiv uses. To get around this error. I tried to upload my version of biblatex.sty. Doing this gives me the following error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
\blx@datamodel@constant@optiondatatypes 
l.5584 ...odel@constant@optiondatatypes\endcsname}

? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
\blx@datamodel@constant@optiondatatypes 
l.5584 ...odel@constant@optiondatatypes\endcsname}

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on arXivSubmission.log.
```

In the biblatex.sty file that I uploaded, here is the line that seems to be causing errors (5584):

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname blx@datamodel@constant@optiondatatypes\endcsname}
```

Doing this with bibtex instead of biber results in the exact same errors. Any help or general advice on uploading to arXiv would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other questions with the error "! Missing \endcsname inserted." were (1) the author had a problem because of Czech characters, and (2) the author had an accented letter in a label. Neither of these things apply in my case. The error message is simply the same, but the actual error is different.

Comment: it should be marked as duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181169/publishing-to-arxiv-using-biblatex-biber so long story short, the answer is: you absolutely must use the same texlive version as arxiv does. Because the .bbl files are not compatible, and arXiv for some reason does not allow running bibtex/biber to generate the correct .bbl themselves.