# Biblatex v3.11 with arXiv - how fix "wrong format version" error?

Tags: biblatex, texlive, biber, arxiv

My problem is related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358831/biblatex-and-arxiv-error) older post. I try to upload my paper to arXiv and get error

```
Package biblatex Warning: File 'main.bbl' is wrong format version
- expected 2.8.
```

I understand from answers to the thread linked above that arXiv uses a fixed biblatex/biber combination (`biblatex` 3.7/Biber 2.7). I found out that I run `biblatex` v 3.11 with Biber 2.11. So while I know the source of my problem I have no clue how to fix it (I am more of a user of LaTeX and not skilled in solving these types of problem). Do you have any advice?

I run Win10 with TexStudio 2.12.8 and MiKTeX 2.9.

I found a longer discussion on this problem [here](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/663); seems to be a hard to solve problem. People suggest to install tex live 2016 with an earlier version of Biblatex 3.5. How should I do this on my system? I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429436/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415703/35864

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same issue, so I hope this gets resolved. I tried downloading Tex Live 2016, but it had `biblatex` one version too early and no clear way to select a version to update to.

Comment: @StardustGogeta Historical TeX live versions are frozen and can not be updated, that means that you cannot change the `biblatex` version of your TeX live 2016. As I wrote in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429445/35864 TeX live 2017 is a better approximation of the arXiv's TeX system as far as `biblatex` and Biber are concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the process that just worked for me in the **exact** same situation.

Go to [the Tex Live 2017 download website](ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/) and download `texlive2017.iso`. Then, mount the file and run `install-tl-windows.bat` and let everything be set to the default. After the installation has finished, open up the command prompt and change the active directory to your LaTeX project directory. There should be two key files there, `***.tex` and a `***.bib` that serves as the bibliography. Delete all compiled copies or logging files. Then, in the command prompt, run the following:

1. `C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe ***.tex`
2. `C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32\biber.exe ***`
3. `C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe ***.tex`
4. `C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe ***.tex`

Finally, upload the files `***.tex` and `***.bbl` to arXiv, and it should work correctly.

Note: If your paper has any figures or diagrams, I would think that you would upload those as well (and not delete them with the other auxiliary files) but I have not tested this myself and cannot be sure.